# Reverse of an array doesn't works

Tags: c, algorithm, reverse

This is my main:

```
int main(){
    int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int i = 0;
    reverse(array,6);

    for(i=0; i < 6; i++)
       printf("%d\n",array[i]);

}
```

and this is my reverse function:

```
void reverse(int * array,int n){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < n; i++){
        int tmp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[n-i];
        array[n-i] = tmp; 
    }
}
```

I don't understand why my output is the same as the input:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6

Is my function call no side effect? What's wrong?

Comment: Reading this may help: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to stop your loop at n/2 otherwise you'll reverse your array (end to n/2) and then you reverse it again (from n/2 to n)

```
void reverse(int * array,int n){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < n/2; i++){
        int tmp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[n-1-i];
        array[n-1-i] = tmp; 
    }
}
```

Moreover you need to use n-1-i instead of n-i

Answer (score 0):

See there are couple of changes you should be doing .

```
void reverse(int * array,int n);
int main(){
    int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int i = 0;
    reverse(array,6);

    for(i=0; i < 6; i++)
       printf("%d\n",array[i]);

}

void reverse(int array[],int n){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i <= ((n/2)-1); i++){
        int tmp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[n-i-1];
        array[n-i-1] = tmp; 
    }
}
```

Output :

6
5
4
3
2
1

Comment: please explain a bit what you did / what he has to do. Don't just dump the code solution.

Comment: also, your answer doesn't add anything to the answer granmirupa posted half an hour before you.